# IE Ctrl-F does not find words in bootstrap panel

Tags: internet-explorer

Using the Ctrl-F function in IE-8 does not find words wrapped in Bootstrap Panel. Mac Chrome, FF and Win FF are finding them correctly. It is not a IE search misconfiguration because the search works on other sites correctly.

```
<div class="marglinleft4"><div class="panel panel-default">

                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <!-- only released components are shown for read only users (others are feeded by uid = 0) -->

                                    <a href="index.php?id=403&amp;no_cache=1&amp;tx_exa_exafe%5Bcomponent%5D=959&amp;tx_exa_exafe%5Baction%5D=show&amp;tx_exa_exafe%5Bcontroller%5D=Component&amp;cHash=515e3bcb19968119673e6639b11c465f">
                                        9.3.1 Einleitung
                                    </a>&nbsp;<small>(Ebene 4, xyz)</small> 


                        </div>

            </div>
            </div>
```

[image: Word "Einleitung" should be marked]

addition 8th july:
On highest hierarchy we have 3 div with "container" class:

```
<div class="container"><f:render section="breadcrumb" /></div>
  <div class="container"><f:render section="main" /></div>
  <div class="container"><f:render section="footer" /></div>
```

If we remove the second class="container" then the IE serach works well...

any idea?

Comment: Bootstrap has a hard time being supported in IE 8, this may be a downfall because of that.

Comment: added infos in original post div class="container"